# on HttpException not being caught

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to handle http errors so I've created custom http exception class

```
class HttpException implements Exception {
  final String message;
  HttpException(this.message);
  @override
  String toString() {
    return message;
  }
}
```

and throwing it on http error

```
   Future<void> createProfile(Profile profile) async {
    try {
      var request =
          new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(APIPath.createProfile()));
          ...
      final response = await request.send();
      if (response.statusCode != 201) {
        ...
        throw HttpException(jsonResponse["error"]);
      }

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.runtimeType); //<= prints HttpException
      throw error; 
    }
  }
```

when I try to catch it then it is caught only in exception and not in HttpExeption

```
      try {
        await Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).createProfile(profile);

      } on HttpException catch (error) {
        print('Http exception'); //<- this is never reached
      } on Exception catch (error) {
        print(error.runtimeType); // <= prints HttpException
        print('exception'); //<- http exception caught here;
      } catch (error) {
        print('error'); 
      }
```

is there any chance to handle http exception in on HttpException?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216111/discussion-on-question-by-delmin-on-httpexception-not-being-caught).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpException` class from [dart-io](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/HttpException-class.html) is being referenced instead of the custom 'HttpException'.

Comment: What a silly stupid mistake.. I have spent half of the day with it... I can not believe it.. Thanks again